# What is the difference between unmoderated and unapproved users?

Tags: user-roles

I recently ran into these two user categories/roles on an existing site for a new client. Most of my client sites are more informational than transactional, so I'm guessing that the categories/roles were added by one or more of the plugins related to e-commerce.

I am looking for information as to what may have added these categories/roles and what the difference is.

Comment: You'll have to work out which plugin(s) added these roles to your site. There's no way we can guess what plugins you might be running.

Comment: That is helpful! I wasn't sure if those words were attached to some standard or common definition.